# Form data keep going to the first row and doesn't move down to the following row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using form in excel to make date entry in Database excel sheet. my first row is in line 7. 1st date entered went in row 7. the 2nd form entry still went and replace the data in row 7 instead of going to row 8. i know i need to make the last row +1 but i don't get it

```
Dim last_row As Long
last_row = database.Range("D1").Value + 7
database.Range("b" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C4").Value
database.Range("c" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C5").Value
database.Range("d" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C6").Value
database.Range("e" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C7").Value
database.Range("f" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C8").Value
database.Range("g" & last_row).Value = form.Range("C9").Value
form.Range("c4:c6").ClearContents
MsgBox "data has been submitted"
```

Comment: `database.Range("D1").Value + 7` will always give you `7` Find last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: `last_row = database.Range("D" & database.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`